# SQL How to get the ending number

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I was using follow function to get numbers from a string.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric
(@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @intAlpha INT
    SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
    BEGIN
        WHILE @intAlpha > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
            SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
        END
    END
    RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
GO
```

And the usage of it helped in most cases.

But not in all.

Strings looks like this:

```
string-goes-here-123450
string-2-goes-here-1233
```

In the first case, output was correct which is 123450, but in second, the output was 21233.

My question is how can i just get the last bit of ending number which separates from "-"

Comment: why isn't 21233 correct?

Comment: because the ending number is the product_id that i need

Comment: is this mysql or sql server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table #test(
    input varchar(50)
)
go
insert into #test values
    ('string-goes-here-123450'),
    ('string-2-goes-here-1233')
go
select t.input, right(t.input,charindex('-',reverse(t.input))-1) as output
from #test t
```

produces:-

```
input                    output
string-goes-here-123450  123450
string-2-goes-here-1233  1233
```

Answer (score 1):

try this... first find the last occurance of `-` and then take the end of the string

```
SET @pos = LEN(@string) - CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(@string))

select  substr(@string, @pos+1, @len(@str))
```

EDIT:  it might be `@pos-1`... I don't have sql server on this computer so I can't test and the functions for mysql are different enough that I'm not sure I translated it correctly.  Please try this out and let me know.